# Chrome Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm running this script in order to display different menu for mobile:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        if ($(window).width() > 750){
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix' ) ); ?>
        }else{
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mobile', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix' ) ); ?>
        }
    });
</script>
```

But I get error by chrome "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" pointing my to that line:

[image]
I can't figure whats wrong with the code, any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**: well, didn't know there is a problem running php inside js.
So what's the proper solution to my situation? I know I can just use css media queries and the display property, but it's bad for the performance, isn't it?

Comment: It's because your PHP code is generating HTML within a JS `script` block - hence the syntax error. I'm not really sure what you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: What are u trying to achieve with php code?

Comment: I'm trying to  display menu that was register with `register_nav_menu()`

Comment: If you use media queries the impact on performance will be insignificant as the navigation will be set to display:none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply output HTML code inside a Javascript block. And since PHP runs on server side, it is not able to get screen sizes.

One thing you may do is to output the HTML of both menus into hidden `<div>` tags:

```
<div id='menu_primary' style="display:none">
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div id='menu_mobile' style="display:none">
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mobile', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix' ) ); ?>
</div>
```

then decide which one to show when the page is loaded:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        if ($(window).width() > 750){
            $('#menu_primary').show();
        }else{
            $('#menu_mobile').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

*(Update. Thanks to Rafi for reminder.)*

The original solution simply adjusted the jquery call to make it works. But it only detect screen size once when page is loaded. A better way to achieve responsiveness is to use CSS media query, which will show / hide different menu versions dynamically when screen size changes:

```
<div id='menu_primary'>Primary</div>
<div id='menu_mobile'>Mobile</div>

<!-- CSS media query within a stylesheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  #menu_primary { display: none; }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  #menu_mobile { display: none; }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I would hide one or the other using media queries in CSS.